# Reading data via GPIO

Tags: digital-logic, analog, gpio

I have just learned GPIO and I've read a lot of in internet. As I understood GPIO port can be at one of two states: `out` and `in`. In any states it can work with `0` and `1`. For example, if we need to turn on a LED we change state to `out` and send `1`. But I can't understand what happens when we connect to GPIO temperature sensor. It is clear that we change state to `in`. But what do we read from GPIO? `0`s and `1`? How can we get the temperature? Please, explain.

P.S. I use Olinuxino A13 board and currently I don't have any sensors. I just want to understand how it generally works and buy after that.

Comment: As CL has commented, please update your question by adding the extra information you have written in comments. This helps the community answer one consistent question, and saves us effort reading all of the comments. Please read the [help] to help you better understand how to ask questions that get good answers.

Comment: @gbulmer I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Allwinner A13 does *not* have any Analogue-to-Digital-Converter (ADC) inputs.

According the the User Manual:

> **2.8 I2C and SPI under Debian**
>   I2C and SPI are both supported in the latest Debian releases. There is respective kernel support for both.
>   There is a python module called pyA13 might be found here:
>   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyA13 It does have I2C (aka TWI) and SPI.

The I2C pins are described in section **6.3 UEXT module** of the User Manual

So a straightforward way to interface the Olinuxino A13 to a temperature sensor is to get a temperature sensor with a built-in I2C interface, run Debian, and get at the temperature sensor form Python. I would expect to also be able to get at I2C from C, but I didn't see that mentioned)

There are quite a lot of I2C temperature sensors. They vary by operating voltage, resolution, and device package. I recommend trying to get things working quickly and cheaply first.

For example [Microchip Temperature Sensors](http://www.microchip.com/ParamChartSearch/chart.aspx?branchID=9001&mid=11&lang=en&pageId=79) include devices with an I2C/SMBus. Some of these come in a Dual-In-Line package, which you can plug into a breadboard, and hence make it relatively easy to test things. Microchip parts are carried by a lot of distributers, so it shouldn't be too hard to get some (You should be able to pick one up for about 1GBP ($1.50))

There are I2C temperature sensors from other manufacturers which may have benefits. I've used Microchip I2C sensors, they are cheap and they worked.

If you really want to, you could buy an external ADC, and interface to that. Their are ADC devices which provide parallel data transfer, so you could experiment with GPIO. Some support SPI. This would require more electronics than an I2C temperature sensor. Hence I'd recommend getting a couple of I2C temperature sensors anyway. They should make it easy to set things up, and might still be useful, to to give you a way to do temperature comparison, (which may help debug the system) if you decide to go analogue.

Answer (score 5):

As you are dealing with temperature sensor here, so you need to use `Analog to digital converter` (ADC). You will have to put values into the ADC registers and then read the incoming values from ADC channel.

You have not mentioned which Micro controller you are focusing, so I am assuming `Atmega32`. You will have to read its datasheet to understand the ADC registers and you will have to make a function to read the values coming from the ADC channel and those values will be your temperature values.

For example:

```
 //function to read adc value
 uint16_t adc_read(uint8_t ch)
{
    ch &= 0b00000111;  
    ADMUX = (ADMUX & 0xF8)|ch;    
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);
    while(ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC));
    return (ADC);
}
```

so in your main, all you need to do is read values using above function and store it in a variable.

```
int main()
{
  uint16_t adc_result0;
  while(1)
  {
    adc_result0 = adc_read(0); //reading values and storing it in variable for further processing.
  }
}
```

**Note**: Above functions are just for the demo purpose and may not give the actual output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use olinuxino A13. I've checked its datasheet there is now a word about ADC, but there are about 70 GPIO. How to understand it?

Comment: Datasheet is the only friend you have while working on the board. For GPIOs you will have to read the pin description of your MCU.

Comment: What do you mean under MCU?

Comment: You will have to look for the pin configuration of the microcontroller/processor used in your board. Then look for the schematics of the board to understand which GPIO is connected to the pins available in your board

Comment: @JimJim2000 All relevant information (such as which temp sensor you're using) belongs into the question.

Comment: Thank you! And the last question. As I've understood one gpio port represents a bit connected to a particular pin. So if I have a digital temperature sensor which can measure temperature from 0 to 31 degree I will need to use 5 GPIO ports to read five bits and to get final temperature?

Comment: @JimJim2000 It is unlikely that your sensor has a parallel output. But how should we know?

Comment: @CL. Thank you for your help. I am a very very newbie in GPIO and I try to understand how to read data from sensors. What I've read is GPIO digital ports ( http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/gpio.txt ) so how can I get data from ONE GPIO PORT? I thought maybe temperature sensors usually send signal to several ports.

Comment: There is no "usual" temperature sensor; all are different. I am asking you for the third time: which sensor?

Comment: @CL. I don't have any sensors. I just try to understand how it works before buying some one.

Comment: That depends on which sensor you'll be buying.

Comment: There are digital and analog sensors. Analog sensors can have amplifiers and conversion functions for ex. the temp. is emitted as a voltage. You'll need an external ADC or an embedded one in your MCU to convert the reading into a number. Digital sensors have an included ADC and provide the temp. value via broadcast or register interface. Register interfaces can be accessed by OneWire, TwoWire/I2C, SPI ...